# Convert string in list objects to comma separated

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of objects, where one of the instance variables in the object is string.
I would like to convert the string variables in the object list into a single comma-separated string.

For example,

I have an object employee as below.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Consider a list of employees,

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>
Employee emp1 = new Employee ("Emp 1",25);
Employee emp2 = new Employee ("Emp 2",25);
empList.add(emp1);
empList.add(emp2);
```

Expected output (Type : String):

```
Emp 1,Emp 2
```

I know it can be done through looping. But I'm looking for some sophisticated ways to do it and keep the code simpler.

Comment: Do the looping. There is no magical "do what I think I would want you to do" function...

Comment: The sophisticated way will contain a loop in it somewhere.

Comment: Hide your loop behind a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `toString()` method in the `Employee` class

```
public String toString() {
   return name;
}
```

Then, print the list:

```
String listToString = empList.toString();
System.out.println(listToString.substring(1, listToString.length() - 1));
```

This is not that *sophisticated* way to print it, but I doesn't involve the usage of third-party libraries.

If you'd like to use third party libraries, here are several way you can print the list.

```
// Using Guava
String guavaVersion = Joiner.on(", ").join(items);

// Using Commons / Lang
String commonsLangVersion = StringUtils.join(items, ", ");
```

Comment: ... and there is the loop. OP wants it _without that_. (even though that is not possible...)

Comment: OCD comment: you will have an extra `,`.

Comment: Fixed it. Now it should be fine, although the approach is not my favourite.

Comment: Do not need duplicates in final output.. Any way to do that ?

Comment: Then you should change the structure to some implementation of the `Set` interface, because it doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: I have another question.. Actually i am currently using toString() to log the value of the object. As i have used the toString() for getting the name alone i could not log the object values. Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to convert the string variables in the object list in to a single comma separated string.

- implement your own `toString()`:

  ```
  public String toString() { return name; }
  ```
- call method `toString()` on your `java.util.List`:

  ```
  empList.toString();
  ```
- get rid of `'['` and `']'`:

  ```
  String s = empList.toString();
  s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
  ```

Comment: This will add fluff like square brackets around the output, and can change (even though that is quite unlikely)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that is true. But it still ties the whole stuff to one implementation of List.toString(). Not reusable code is not good code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real clean way to do this, use function literals in Java 8.  Otherwise,

In Employee class:

`public String toString() { return name; }`

Print out the list, removing the square brackets

`list.toString().replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]", "$1");`

Answer (score 0):

Without loop ,Using `list.toString()`

```
public class Employee {

     public Employee(String string, int i) {
        this.age=i;
        this.name=string;
    }
    private String name;
     private int age;

     @Override
     public String toString() {
           return name + " " + age;
        }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         Employee emp1 = new Employee ("Emp 1",25);
         Employee emp2 = new Employee ("Emp 2",25);
         empList.add(emp1);
         empList.add(emp2);
         System.out.println(empList.toString().
                       substring(1,empList.toString().length()-1));
}
}
```

Prints

```
Emp 1 25, Emp 2 25
```

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It is mock code,OP can remove/add as per his requirments :)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, using the Java 8 Stream API:

```
String res = String.join(",", empList.stream().map(c -> c.getName()).toList());
```